# Include files/folders in zip in powershell upon exact Match

Tags: windows, powershell, split, exact-match

Below are my files

```
1. C:\Temp\src\config\1.txt
2. C:\Temp\src\logs\wowconfigls\3.txt
```

The user wants to include the files/folders that exactly match either `canweb.war` or `config`.

Thus, `$itemsToInclude = "canweb.war,config"`

The below approach creates a zip that includes both 1.txt and 3.txt however, it should not have included `3.txt` as it is inside the folder `wowconfigls` which is not an exact match provided by the user.

Only `config` should have matched.

```
# Set the name of the zip file including the build number

  $zipFileName = "C:\Temp\package-165.zip"

  cd "C:\Temp"

  $itemsToInclude = "canweb.war,config"

  Write-Host "itemsToInclude is- $itemsToInclude"

 

  if (-not (Test-Path $zipFileName)) {

    $null = New-Item $zipFileName -ItemType File

  }

  $workspace = "C:\Temp"

  if ($itemsToInclude -eq '*') {

  # Include all files, including files from subdirectories

  Write-Host "Include all files, including files from subdirectories"

  Get-ChildItem -Path $workspace -Recurse -File |

    Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipFileName  -Update -Force

  } else {

 

  # Include specific files as per the comma-separated list

  Write-Host 'Include specific files as per the comma-separated list'

  $pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

  Write-Host "PATTERN is: $pattern"

  $filesToInclude = Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File | Where-Object FullName -Match $pattern

  #$filesToInclude = Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq $pattern }

  #Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq $pattern }

  #Where-Object FullName -eq $pattern

 

  $filesToInclude | ForEach-Object {

    $newZipEntrySplat = @{

      EntryPath   = $_.FullName.Substring($workspace.Length)

      SourcePath  = $_.FullName

      Destination = $zipFileName

     }

     New-ZipEntry @newZipEntrySplat

    }

    #Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipFileName -Update

  }
itemsToInclude is- canweb.war,config
Include specific files as per the comma-separated list
PATTERN is: canweb\.war|config


   Directory: src/config/

EntryType               LastWriteTime  CompressedSize            Size EntryName                                                                                          
---------               -------------  --------------            ---- ---------                                                                                          
Archive            12/6/2023  7:43 AM         9.00  B         7.00  B 1.rtf                                                                                              
Archive            12/6/2023  7:43 AM         0.00  B         0.00  B 2.docx                                                                                             


   Directory: src/logs/wowconfigls/

EntryType               LastWriteTime  CompressedSize            Size EntryName                                                                                          
---------               -------------  --------------            ---- ---------                                                                                          
Archive            12/6/2023  7:43 AM         0.00  B         0.00  B 3.txt
```

I understand that `Where-Object { $_.FullName -ieq $pattern }` or `Where-Object { $_.FullName -ilike $pattern }` should help but the `$pattern` needs to be considered comma-separated one at a time.

Can you please suggest how can I achieve an exact match?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this: `$pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'`

This gives you: `$pattern = "canweb\.war|config"`

This pattern will return `*canweb.war*` and `*config*` since `-match` looks for the exact part of the string that matches. It's likely `canweb.war` will be the last part of the file path (`FullName`) and be okay.

What you need to change is to make the pattern string include more details.

`$pattern = "\\canweb\.war$|\\config\\"` should return the correct files your looking for.

`canweb.war` would always appear at the end of the `FullName` attribute, so using `$` to indicate that string should have what we are looking for at the end. For `\\config\\`, we escape the folder path to match the folder itself. Although this will match `startingpath\config\*`, so sub-folders would be included too.

EDIT: If the pattern needs to be generated from a CLI parameter `$pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({if($_.contains('.')){[regex]::Escape($_+"$");} else { [regex]::Escape("\"+$_+"\"); } }) -join '|'` would work a little better. Single words would be treated as a folder and `file.ext` will see the `.` and add `$` to the end to indicate it's a file.

Comment: I understand the desired pattern you suggested ... however can you help construct that pattern no matter how many files or folders are for input?

Comment: Also, the user may wish to include a folder with relative path like "canweb.war,config,\src\logs\xml" in which case I would like to perform the search for files in `xml` folder inside `\src\logs` location.

Comment: In a way so the script could ingest it from the command line? Just split the string as per normal but look for `.` in the section and add slashes when no dot is found. `$pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({if($_.contains('.')){[regex]::Escape($_);} else { [regex]::Escape("\"+$_+"\"); } }) -join '|'` (probably not the cleanest way but works)